# Generating vulkan_wrapper.h/cpp

Tags: android, vulkan

I'm trying to write a barebones Vulkan app on Android. I'm finding that most of Google's example apps rely on `vulkan_wrapper.h` and `vulkan_wrapper.cpp`. Google's [Vulkan documentation](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/graphics/getting-started.html#using) also says to use them.

I would love to use them but they are part of the example projects' code, not the SDK, and the header says that they are generated. So how is a developer supposed to generate them for their project? I have copied them from a sample app for the time being but am curious what the best practice is for generating them and keeping them up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how they're generated, but you could just copy them into your project. There shouldn't be much need to regenerate them, since they only contain the core and WSI extension entrypoints normally provided by libvulkan.so; even if you regenerate it, it won't contain other extensions that might have been added to vulkan.h.

The only reason to use these is if you want to avoid linking against libvulkan.so directly, which only matters if you want your app to load and run on devices that don't have it (Marshmallow and older).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure How they get generated but you can do something like that if you want it to. Vulkan layers come with the scripts and the xml file, you can modify the script to your requirements. We are already doing that in our projects. The script can be found here.

https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers/tree/master/scripts